# How to find cordova app screen showing after starting activity with webintent?

Tags: cordova, meteor, android-webview, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova [webintent](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) plugin in order to launch location settings screen. How do we know app returned after

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({action:'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS'},
                    function(){console.log("GPS settings screen showing now"); waitForGPS();},
                    function(){console.log("Unable to show GPS settings screen")});
```

and for waiting an recursive function

```
    function waitForGPS(){
      CheckGPS.check(function(){
            //GPS is enabled!
            onDeviceOK();

        },
        function(){
            //GPS is disabled!
            waitForGPS();

        });
}
```

Usual cordova events pause and resume do not fire up when this activity is launched or closed.
Is there any alternative to handle this scenario as, if user do not enables GPS the app will be struck in infinite loop.